# A problem related to complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let P be a polynomial of degree n. Assume that |P(z)| ≤ M for |z| = 1. Show that |P(z)| ≤ M|z|^n for |z| ≥ 1.

I don't know how to begin on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the holomorphic function $f(z) = z^n P(\frac{1}{z})$.  Apply the maximum modulus principle to $f$.

Comment: Hint: When following JHF's hint start to show, that f extends holomorphically to the origin $z=0$.